# Freeze the first column of a responsive table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have a responsive table whose first column I wish to freeze. I took reference from Stack Overflow and tried the code on my table.

CSS code:

```
.table-responsive>.fixed-column {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
    var $table = $('.table');
    //Make a clone of our table
    var $fixedColumn = $table.clone().insertBefore($table).addClass('fixed-column');

    //Remove everything except for first column
    $fixedColumn.find('th:not(:first-child),td:not(:first-child)').remove();

    //Match the height of the rows to that of the original table's
    $fixedColumn.find('tr').each(function (i, elem) {
        $(this).height($table.find('tr:eq(' + i + ')').height());
    });
});
```

However this code is not working, can anyone tell how to make this thing work, complete code at [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/learner001/96yprzp0/1/)

Comment: this works: http://jsfiddle.net/96yprzp0/2/ , you were missing the table variable

Comment: what does *freeze* mean in this context? fixed size (width)? uneditable content?

Comment: @BhavO can u tel why the first column is appearing as invisible, can i make it more prominent

Comment: @hoijui by freeze i mean that the first column should remain fixed and the rest of the column should be allowed to scroll horizontally

Comment: @kavi i have set the table bg color to white, take a look http://jsfiddle.net/96yprzp0/3/

Comment: @BhavO it seems to work in fiddle but with my theme its not working

Comment: you can adjust the css for the table, change the background color and color to suite your theme, update jsfiddle with your theme if you can